# Recursive string swap

Tags: c++, string, recursion

I'm trying to swap two indexes of a string recursively but i've been getting a segmentation fault. Can anybody show me where i'm going wrong? This is all in a void function that takes three arguments, words(the string), and first and last as the positions to swap

```
int count = 0;
if(words.length() == 0)
    return;


if(words.length() < last)
    return;
if(words[first] > words[last])
    return;

if(words.at(first + 1)){
    words[first] = words[last + count];
    reverseit(words, first, last);
}
if(words.length() >= last){
    words[last - 1] = words[last];
    words[last] = words[last -1];
//  words[first + 1] = words[first];
//  words[first] = words[first +1];
    count++;
    reverseit(words, first, last);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  In this case, we should get a driver program and the full error message.  "Getting a seg fault" doesn't come up to standards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to figure out what your function is supposed to do from either your description or your code.  Here's my best guess -- if it's wrong, please update your question accordingly:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void reverseit(std::string &words, size_t first, size_t last) {

    size_t length = words.length();

    if (length == 0 || last > length || first >= last) {
        return;
    }

    char temp = words[last];
    words[last] = words[first];
    words[first] = temp;

    reverseit(words, first + 1, last - 1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    std::string str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    reverseit(str, 6, 18);

    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
> ./a.out
abcdefsrqponmlkjihgtuvwxyz
>
```